# java jni use 32 bit binaries on 64 bit system

Tags: java, java-native-interface, binaryfiles, win64

I'm using a JNI library in my Java project.  The library only provides windows binaries for x86.  When I run the program, it gives me an error about not being able to run 32 bit binaries on a 64 bit system.  (I'm on Win64).  Is there a way to run 32 bit binaries on a 64 bit system? would using a 32 bit version of java/launching the program in 32 bit mode work?  Could I convert/re-compile the binaries for x64? (I don't have the original native source).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run 32 bit code in a 64 bit JVM. It's impossible to load 32 bit code in a 64 bit process and it's impossible to obtain the binaries without recompiling the source code, the only possible solution is to install a 32 bit JVM.